# Generate the report in table format

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have created pipeline to start and stop the 100+ database and my pipeline is working successfully, and I am getting email also post success or failure of result.

Now I want with this pipeline I need to get report also in table format or any other format like as below.

```
DB name  DBstatus Listnerstatus
DB1       UP         UP
DB2       DOWN       DOWN
```

or result like

```
DBName status
DB1     success
DB1     Fail
```

How can I achieve this?

I have already tried with publish to HTML, but it is not working

[script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdhPp.png)

Comment: Please include your code as text formatted as code into your question and don't include your code as picture.

Comment: can any one help here